# I have to find common elements between two arrays multidimensional and jagged array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have to find common elements between the two arrays that are multidimensional and jagged and print them only once. I wrote some code and got the output but it's printing all the common elements from array 1 and array 2 it has to print only once.
I mean if array 1 is[5, 5,3] array 2 is [5, 5, 6,2] output is [5, 5, 5,5]. I have to print 5 only one time.

Here I have already stopped printing duplicate elements multiple times from array 2 for that I inserted boolean tags.
But can't able to stop from array 1. For the example Have to take 5 elements 1 time and check if it is available in array 2, if it is there then print 5 as output.

```java
int[][] arr1 = new int[][]{{1, 2, 1}, {9, 7, 2}, {7, 3, 6}};

int[][] arr2 = new int[][]{{2, 6, 8}, {0, 1, 7}, {7, 2, 0}, {8, 3}};

System.out.println("Input 1:");
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1[i]));
}
System.out.println("Input 2:");
for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2[j]));
}

boolean duplicate = false;

for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; j++) {
        int transpose = 0;
        transpose = arr1[i][j];

        for (int k = 0; k < arr2.length; k++) {
            duplicate = false;
            for (int l = 0; l < arr2[k].length; l++) {
                if (transpose == arr2[k][l]) {
                    System.out.println(transpose);
                    duplicate = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (duplicate) break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) Firstly, your code does not compile (Look at the line `if (duplicate)`: The `}` is before the `break; `which does not work). I edited the code how I think you meant it. Secondly, I am not sure that I understand what your requirement is. Do you want to find numbers that are present in both arrays (aka 1, 2, 7, 3 in your example) or does the position of the array elements matter somehow? Cheers :)

Comment: @vatbub 6 is also present in both arrays.

Comment: Ah, true, I missed that (can't edit my comment anymore though)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're directly printing elements when found. This causes duplicates from `arr1` to be printed.

Consider using a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html) to store unique elements found in both arrays and eliminate duplicates. Then print the set:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr1 = new int[][]{{1, 2, 1}, {9, 7, 2}, {7, 3, 6}};
        int[][] arr2 = new int[][]{{2, 6, 8}, {0, 1, 7}, {7, 2, 0}, {8, 3}};
        Set<Integer> commonSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; ++j) {
                int val = arr1[i][j];
                if (commonSet.contains(val)) continue;
                for (int k = 0; k < arr2.length; ++k) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < arr2[k].length; ++l) {
                        if (val == arr2[k][l]) {
                            commonSet.add(val);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(commonSet);
    }
}
```

The time complexity of this approach (base on your original code) is `O(n × max(m) x p × max(q))`...

- `n` is the number of rows in `arr1`.
- `max(m)` is the maximum number of columns in any row of `arr1`.
- `p` is the number of rows in `arr2`.
- `max(q)` is the maximum number of columns in any row of `arr2`.

Basically, it's a nested loop through both arrays. Not efficient for large arrays.

If efficiency is a requirement, try this, which is `O(n × max(m) + p × max(q))`:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr1 = new int[][]{{1, 2, 1}, {9, 7, 2}, {7, 3, 6}};
        int[][] arr2 = new int[][]{{2, 6, 8}, {0, 1, 7}, {7, 2, 0}, {8, 3}};
        Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Integer> commonSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr1[i].length; ++j) {
                set1.add(arr1[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2[i].length; ++j) {
                if (set1.contains(arr2[i][j])) {
                    commonSet.add(arr2[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(commonSet);
    }
}
```

**Example output for both approaches:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

*Note: a `HashSet` does not provide any method to maintain insertion order (use a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) instead) or keep sorted order (use a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) instead.)*

Answer (score 1):

Let's create a set to be able to determine whether an item was already found.

This will be a set that will store the common numbers found so far. Now, let's loop your arrays:

```
Set<Integer> found = new HashSet<Integer>();
//Looping the rows of the first array
for (int outer1 = 0; outer1 < arr1.length; outer1++) {
    //Looping the cells of the first array's current element
    for (int inner = 0; inner < arr1[outer1].length; inner++) {
        //Looping the rows of the second array
        for (int outer2 = 0; outer2 < arr2.length; outer2++) {
            if (found.contains(arr1[outer1][inner])) continue;
            //Is arr1[outer1][inner] a common item?
            if (ArrayUtils.indexOf(arr2[outer2], arr1[outer1][inner]) >= 0)
                //If so, have we found it already?
                if (!found.contains(arr1[outer1][inner])) {
                    //No, this is the first time we find this particular common item
                    //So we add it
                    found.add(arr1[outer1][inner]);
                    //And print it
                    System.out.println(arr1[outer1][inner]);
                    //Let's force moving forward:
                    outer2 = arr2.length;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We therefore:

- loop the first array

  - loop the items of the current item of the first array

    - loop the second array

      - check whether the current inner item of the first array is inside the current array of the second array

        - if so, we check whether it's new

          - if so, we add it to the set so we will not print it again
          - and print it

EDIT:

As @Eritrean pointed out in the comment section, Java has no method called `indexOf` for arrays and the initial version of the code would not compile. Hence, I edited the code above by using `ArrayUtils`'s `indexOf` instead (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#indexOf-boolean:A-boolean-)

If one does not want to use that, he/she can implement an `indexOf` method that will return the index of an item in an array or -1 if not found, or loop the inner arrays of the second array as well.

Comment: An array has no `indexOf` method. This line will not compile: `if(arr2[outer2].indexOf(...`

Comment: @Eritrean good point, it's been a while since I last worked with Java. Fixing, editing.

Comment: @Eritrean edited my answer accordingly. Thanks again!